# Hola buenas tengo un problema con php quiero guardar los datos un array y me muestra este error , SQLSTATE HY093 número de parámetros invalidos

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Cuando lo ejecuto me da este error Hola buenas tengo un problema con php, SQLSTATE HY093 Invalid parameter number parameter was not defined. Aqui es dejo el codigo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. 2. ¡Hay que leer los mensajes de error! Volvé a mirar tu código, y fijate si los parámetros nombrados que escogiste realmente existen (pista: no, no existen). 3. [phpmyadmin] nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que quiero saber es como arreglar el problema por que me dice que el número de parámetros es invalidos

Comment: De vuelta: _Volvé a mirar tu código, y fijate si los parámetros **nombrados** que escogiste realmente existen (pista: no, no existen)._ De hecho, no estás mostrando ningún código, así que _adivino lo que está en una imagen invisible_.

Comment: Va a resultar un poco complicado ayudarte si no podemos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y coloca el código.

Comment: Eh puesto unas fotos con el codigo